# How do I post on Facebook User's wall?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> I have some Facebook user in my database with their facebook id which is I have got after they login via my facebook app. Now I want to post their wall after a certain period using php.
>
> I have got their user id using below code-

```
include_once "facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  'secret' => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  'cookie' => true,
));

$user       = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    print_r($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

> I have got their id from $user_profile variable.
>
> I am using this scope to login **"email,publish_actions"**
>
> Please give me some sample code if possible, I'm too much worry about this :(
>
> Sorry for my poor English

Comment: Posting on a users wall is not allowed. The user need to trigger the post.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2nd October 2013 you can no longer post to another user's wall using the API:

> **Removing the ability to post to friends' timelines via API**
>
> We have found that posting content via API (stream.publish) on a
>   friend's wall lead to a high incidence of user dissatisfaction (hiding
>   content, blocking the app). After the migration period, posting
>   content to friends' timelines via stream.publish will no longer be
>   allowed. Please use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) for posting.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/migrations/completed-changes